# MariaDB InnoDB - is it more efficient to store text fields in a different table?

Tags: database, database-design, mariadb, innodb, mariadb-10.1

Using MariaDB 10.1 and InnoDB table, is there still a benefit in storing TEXT fields in a different table, if the text field is going to be less-commonly referenced? I believe it was the done thing a few years ago, not sure it still applies.

Row count is ~80K and inserts/updates not very frequent (it's for product description). Let's assume we're not using SELECT * everywhere!

Comment: Usually not worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

Such technical details typically only become relevant in highly frequented tables and/or huge tables.
In your case (80k rows, rare DML, NOT SELECT *) neither of these 2 criteria are given and so I would NOT consider to make it overcomplicated and keep everything in one single table.

If you HAVE highly frequented tables and/or huge tables it can make sense to separate a few columns from the main table. But now it becomes very complicated. If you want to read all the details I recommend first:

- Externally Stored Fields in InnoDB
  https://mysqlserverteam.com/externally-stored-fields-in-innodb/

And then:

- The BLOB and TEXT Types
  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html
- How Compression Works for InnoDB Tables
  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-compression-internals.html
- InnoDB Row Formats
  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-row-format.html

Just keep in mind: In MariaDB 10.3.7 and later, the InnoDB implementation has diverged substantially from the InnoDB in MySQL. Therefore, in these versions, the InnoDB version is no longer associated with a MySQL release version.

Here a short comparison matrix:

| MariaDB | InnoDB |
| --- | --- |
| 10.0 | 5.6 |
| 10.1 | 5.6 |
| 10.2 | 5.7 |
| 10.3* | 5.7, diverged |
| 10.4* | diverged |
| 10.5* | diverged |
| 10.6* | diverged |

Unfortunately we do not have much documentation about MariaDB internals. One has to search in MariaDB's Jira: https://jira.mariadb.org